# Min/Max of a function

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Can someone answer these, (You can by a **LOGICAL** Yes or No only, or by a proof).

1)$A \subset B \Rightarrow$

$\min${$f(x)$ s.t $x \in A$}$\le \min${$f(x)$ s.t $x \in B$}

2)$A \subset B \Rightarrow$

$\max${$f(x)$ s.t $x \in A$}$\le \max${$f(x)$ s.t $x \in B$}

Comment: what have you tried ? where are you stuck ? what is $f$ ? Your question is missing context... -1 for an unclear statement.

Comment: 1) No 2) Yes ${}$

Comment: @Tavish So 1) is true as this? 1)$A \subset B \Rightarrow$ $\min${$f(x)$ s.t $x \in A$}$\ge \min${$f(x)$ s.t $x \in B$} Or we cant say in general?

Comment: @sara That is true.